# How can I prevent the element behind a semi-transparent button from showing?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Consider the following code snippet,

```css
.border {
   border: 4px solid rgb(195, 0, 38);
}

.info-card {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
  background-color: rgb(195, 0, 38);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}

.order-button {
  margin-top: -1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
<div class="info-card">
  <h1> Info Section </h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="order-button">
   <button>
      Order Now
   </button>
</div>
```

**Expected Result:**

Here the disabled button needs to take higher order than the border as like the below image.

[image]

Kindly please don't change/add new color in css as these colors are dynamic from backend and hence unable to hard code some color for button to make it look above the border.

How to make the z-index of button to take higher than the border?

Comment: position them both relative and then give button a higher z-index

Comment: The button already is above the border. The only reason you can see the border at all is because you've made the button transparent with the `opacity` css proprty. Remove that property or set it to `1` if you don't want to see the border.

Comment: you simply add it to the relevant class: `.order-button { ... z-index: 1 }`. Anyway, please consider that as you set the button to be semi-transparent (`button { ... opacity: 0.5; ...}`), you are going to see whatever is beneath it.

Comment: It already is at a higher value than the border, the problem is the opacity.

Comment: I have made the opacity 0.5 because it needs to look like disabled.. It would be good if some one provide me solution making the **disabled button** to be placed above the border.

Comment: @HelloWorld - Well that obviosuly didn't do what you thought it did...

Comment: @HelloWorld That's the reason for the problem though

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. Could you provide me the possible solution to handle in this case? Its okay if I remove opacity but I need to make the background of button similar like that but I cannot add any new color by hard coding unfortunately..

Comment: @MattHamer5, Could you provide me the possible solution to handle in this case? Its okay if I remove opacity but I need to make the background of button similar like that but I cannot add any new color by hard coding unfortunately..

Comment: @HelloWorld, you can obtain the same aspect (minus the transparency) by changing its `background-color` and `border-color` properties rather than the `opacity`.

Comment: @HelloWorld Not sure what you can and can't add to your project, but making it greyscale will have the 'disabled' effect `filter: grayscale(100%);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that you've asked the wrong question. Your button *already* overlays the element with the border, but you've decreased opacity such that it shows through.

To remedy this you can place a background on the element behind the button:

```css
.border {
  border: 4px solid rgb(195, 0, 38);
}

.info-card {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
  background-color: rgb(195, 0, 38);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}

.order-button {
  margin-top: -1.5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <div class="info-card">
    <h1> Info Section </h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="order-button">
   <button>
      Order Now
   </button>
</div>
```

Of course, you could simply use different colors on your button. There doesn't seem to be a benefit to reducing opacity. You say the colors are "dynamic", but they can probably be overridden with CSS.

```css
.border {
  border: 4px solid rgb(195, 0, 38);
}

.info-card {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
  background-color: #E17F92;
  border-color: #ccc;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}

.order-button {
  margin-top: -1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <div class="info-card">
    <h1> Info Section </h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="order-button">
  <button>
      Order Now
   </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You just have to position the button relatively and apply a z-index of 1 to it. You may want to change the transparent background for the button. If you don't, you'll still see the border through the button. ;)

```css
.border {
   border: 4px solid rgb(195, 0, 38);
}

.info-card {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
  background-color: rgb(195, 0, 38);
  opacity: 0.5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}

.order-button {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -1.5rem;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
<div class="info-card">
  <h1> Info Section </h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="order-button">
   <button>
      Order Now
   </button>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve OP's problem, the problem is with the opacity that is set on the button.

Comment: I have noted that too. ;)

Answer (score -1):

Well, you're talking about the `z-index`, but you didn't use it.

**To make sure the button overlaps the border and leaving the structure intact, add this:**

Add: `position: relative;` and `z-index: 1;` to the `button`.

Also, you've given the `button` an `opacity` of `0.5`. Change that to `1.0`
If you leave that as `0.5`, the `button` appears to be under the border, because the border is visible through the `button`. Even though the `button` has a higher `z-index`.

```css
.border {
   border: 4px solid rgb(195, 0, 38);
}

.info-card {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgb(195, 0, 38);
  opacity: 1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
}

.order-button {
  margin-top: -1.5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
<div class="info-card">
  <h1> Info Section </h1>
</div>
</div>
<div class="order-button">
   <button>
      Order Now
   </button>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't retain the intended colors of the button.

Comment: He stated that buttons can be dynamically changed. So retaining that color he used in the example doesn't seem required.